# Python If Statement Never Evaluates to True

Tags: python, if-statement, equality

I apologize if my questions seem trivial.  I would rather ask this in a chat room; however, my reputation is too low at the moment, so I am unable to ask anything in the Python chat room.  I am currently learning Python for a class and the teacher gave us some practice problems to work to get us spun up.  The function I am building now takes a number list and converts it to a string.  The issue that I am having is that my if statement never evaluates to true.  I have tried a few ways to work with the variables and have added many print statements to see if they should ever be equal, but to no avail.  Thanks again in advance.  I promise I am only asking after researching and trying many ways, but am now at a loss...Here is my code:

```
def nlist2string(nlist):
    characters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25']
    newList = []
    nListLen = len(nlist)         # var msgLen will be an integer of the length

    print 'Number list before conversion: ', nlist

    index = 0
    while index < nListLen:
        print 'Index at: ', nlist[index]
        num = nlist[index]
        print 'Is num equal to nlist indexed? ', num
        newNum = num % 26

        i = 0
        while i < 26:
            num1 = newNum
            num2 = numbers[i]
            print 'num1 = ', num1
            print 'num2 = ', num2
            if (num1 == num2):
                newList.append(characters[i])
                print 'Here is the current newList: ', newList
            else:
                print 'They never equal each other.'
            i = i + 1
        index = index + 1
    return newList

    numMessage = [28, 0, 33]
    convertedNumMsg = nlist2string(numMessage)
    print 'Number list after conversion: ', convertedNumMsg
```

Comment: When using a `def` statement, indent all code inside the block by at least one space. Right now you're defining a function by the name of `nlist2string`, but you aren't indenting the code that follows.

Comment: I'm sorry, it actually is indented by 4 spaces in my actual code, but every time I copy my code over, it loses the spacing, so I added it back wrong.  Sorry, not only am I new to Python, I am also new to posting questions on forums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to compare integers to strings, try changing your definition for `numbers` to the following:

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
```

Or alternatively, `numbers = range(26)`.

Currently when comparing `num1` and `num2`, you will be doing comparisons like `4 == '4'`, which will never be true:

```
>>> 4 == '4'
False
```

As an alternative to changing how you create your `numbers` list, you could convert `num2` to an integer or `num1` to a string before the comparison, so either `num1 == int(num2)` or `str(num1) == num2`.

Comment: Alternatively, `num2 = int(numbers[i])`

Comment: A few seconds late. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: A much better way to make that list is: `range(26)`

Comment: @F.J That worked! I new it was something really simple that I was overlooking.  Thank you very much!  Also, thank you Jesse Rusak, I was wondering about casting in Python, I'm sure that will be helpful to me very soon!

Comment: @Asad: how do I use range(26)?  Would it be: ' numbers = [range(26)] '

Comment: @jesiKat No, `range` returns a list, try it in the interpreter.

Comment: @jesiKat `[1,2,3,4,5]` is exactly the same as `range(6)`

Comment: @Asad Don't forget the zero-based indexing, so `range(6)` is `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and `range(1,6)` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of strings, of numbers 0-25.
In Python, a string is never equal to a number, So, `num1 == num2` is always False.

So, it should be

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
```

is more appropriate(and will work).

Or even better

```
numbers = range(26)
```

---

And if you don't want to edit `numbers`'s value, use this conditional:

```
if num1 == int(num2):
```

This will convert num2 into an integer, which is what you want to do.
Also, in that case, you can use [map (Built-in Function)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), for more readability like so:

```
numbers = map(str, range(26))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above properly addresses the question, but as a general tip: when reducing a list of values to a single value, use the `reduce` function. I realise of course that this is a learning exercise, but it can be useful to know the relevant inbuilt function for the job. That makes your function much shorter:

```
def nlist2string(nlist):

    def convert_to_alpha(s):
        if isinstance(s,str): //check if s is already a string
            return s          //if it is, return it unchanged
        else:
            return str(unichr(s+97)) //otherwise, get the corresponding alphabet
                                     //and return that
    def reduce_func(x,y):
        //convert the numbers to alphabets
        //and join the two together
        return convert_to_alpha(x) + convert_to_alpha(y) 

    return reduce(reduce_func, nlist)
```

For example, the output from:

```
l = [7,4,11,11,14]
print nlist2string(l)
```

is the string `"hello"`.

The reduce function takes two arguments, a function that will be used to collapse the list into a single value, and a list.

As a more simple example of what `reduce` does:

```
function add(x,y):
    return x + y

print reduce(add, [1, 4, 3, 10, 5])
//Output: 23
```

Comment: @Schoolboy Why is this overkill? It does exactly the same thing as the program above, but takes a lot less code.

Comment: I just copied this code and tried to run it with my previous nlist and got lots of errors.  I probably need to import some modules and a few other things, but this is definitely way too advanced for me at the moment.  My debugging skills are non-existent/using google. I really appreciate your help though!!  At least I can always reference this and maybe use it in the future!  Thanks @Asad

Comment: @jesiKat Yes, I made a mistake in the code. I've corrected it and put up a demonstration [here](http://ideone.com/rBOtK4)

Comment: @jesiKat Also, no modules are needed, this is native code. I understand how this can be a bit overwhelming though, so it is probably a good idea to stick with the function you're using.

Comment: @Asad, Amazing help, Thank You!!  I had no idea how awesome people on these forums are! Quick question - Is there a way to print my new list ['c','a','h'] as the string 'cah' ?

Comment: @jesiKat Yes. Just use `''.join(['c','a','h'])`. Just to show what the empty string is for, `','.join(['c','a','h'])` returns `"c,a,h"`.

Comment: Great, that worked; however, is there a way to get rid of those commas so that it is just the string 'cah'? (Sorry!!)

Comment: @jesiKat Yes, the first snippet I posted in that comment (`''.join(['c','a','h'])`) joins the list without commas. In general `string.join(yourlist)` joins the elements of the list with separator `string`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, string literals and numbers are separate types of object, and do not compare equal.

```
1 == "1"
```

returns False.

You're iterating through your list of strings of numerals, but it's not a list of actual numbers.

You can use the range() function (it's a python built-in) to generate a number list instead of typing it out by hand.